# Cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I am currently using criteria to retrieve the details of a user, but when trying to query the details object with the right user, I get a ClassCastException.

My Criteria Code;

```
Criteria criteria = sess.createCriteria(UserDetails.class)
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("user.id", user.id));
```

I also tried using;

```
Criteria criteria = sess.createCriteria(UserDetails.class)

Criteria subCriteria = criteria.createCriteria("user");
subCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", user.id));
```

Both give me the ClassCastException. I know I can easily solve it by letting the User implement Serializable, but is there any other solution?

Comment: Why you do not want to implement Serializable?

Comment: I have the feeling that there is a better way to solve it

Comment: Have you checked this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020904/when-and-why-jpa-entities-should-implement-serializable-interface

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only other solution is to implement Externalizable.

Comment: Externalizable extends Serializable so you end up with Serializable any ways.

Comment: @Juha Syrjälä: obviously, but that doesn't make it the same solution. You have to do more work.

Answer (score 48):

For me, the problem was a bug in Hibernate when using non-pk relations: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7668

As a workaround, I implemented Serializable and the exception is gone

Comment: This is saved my time, I don't need to find any other way then for now :)

Comment: Is this a way to solve the issue or it just suppresses the error? Sorry, I'm new to spring Jpa and was trying to join tables with non-primary keys.

Answer (score 35):

You should implement `Serializable` interface.

Comment: OP is asking for *another* solution.

Comment: any instructions for the implementation?

Answer (score 16):

My experience was this. I had a chain of parent/child relationships working. Then, I was forced to refactor. During the process, I failed to update all my annotations correctly. That is when I started receiving the cast to Serializable error. I implemented Serializable, and this exposed the real problems. Once everything was working, I was able to remove Serializable.

So, in answer to your question, the real problem may be in your setup, and Hibernate is trying to work around the issues by serializing certain entities. Try temporarily implementing Serializable to expose the issues, and then removing it.

Comment: In my case it was a `ManyToOne` mapping which had more than one result in a query which produced the `ClassCastException`. Hibernate created a proper Exception after `implements Serializable`.

Comment: In my case, the interface makes it work, but I don't want to have to add it in when I am using hibernate to marshal/unmarshal.

Comment: I tried implementing and everything works fine. Though i can't understand why is it needed as other entities are working fine without implementing `Serializable` .