# Why to implement serializable in entity class

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do Hibernate table classes need to be Serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726300/do-hibernate-table-classes-need-to-be-serializable)

I can perform any CRUD operation using Hibernate in Java and my entity class need not to implement Serializable interface.

But I have read that entity class must implement Serializable. Is there any specific scenario where my entity class must be Serializable?

Answer (score 2):

If your cache provider is configured to overflow to disk, your classes will need to be serializable, at least for ehcache.