# JoinColumn on column created from another join

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have entity User which contains field with entity Actor which contains 
field with entity Product.
Now I want User in database to have information about product id that's being stored in Actor using @JoinColum on Product.
For better clarification, some code:

```
   @Entity
    public class User {
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumns(value = {@JoinColumn(name = "actor_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "product_id")})
        private Actor actor; 

  public Actor getActor() {
        return actor;
    }

    public void setActor(Actor actor) {
        this.actor = actor;
    }
    }

    @Entity
    public class Actor {
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
        private Product product;
    }
```

In database it creates table "users" with "actor_id" and "product_id" and table "actors" with column "product_id".

Using Spring Data Repository's userRepository.findAll() method I end up with ClassCastException and the following message:

> Actor_$$_jvst485_0 cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: implement Serializable interface in your entities

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement Serializable interface in all entities if you are passing detached object of them. This is specified by JSR 220. For more details, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726300/do-hibernate-table-classes-need-to-be-serializable)