# Java Beans: Because implement serializable interface in the following example?

Tags: java, serialization, javabeans

I'm doing a tutorial roseindia.net (http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jdbc/dataaccessobjectdesignpattern.html) and to make the bean `StudentBean.java` implement `java.io.Serializable` interface.

Does this have any reason? Is the data stored differently in the database to implement `Serializable` interface?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020904/when-and-why-jpa-entities-should-implement-serializable-interface

Comment: You are doing a tutorial from perhaps the most notorious site of programming misinformation on the Internet. Please try to find a better one.

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial you linked to does not make use of the class being Serializable.

They might have thrown it in there to follow a general Java bean pattern, but it is not needed for writing it to a database via JDBC. You are rightly confused about this, because there is no explanation.

Serializable is used for ObjectOutputStream, for example to write to files or transfer the bean over the network using RMI. So for a data transport object, this is not a bad feature to support.

Comment: I understand, excellent response, very successful for me. I just have one more question:

I could store the state of my object in the DB as a set of bits implementing serializable interface?

I say this in case you want to store an object with attributes more complex than simple strings or integers (such as a map or an arraylist)

Comment: Yes, you could turn a Serializable object into a byte[] (binary data) and then put that it the DB. But then it cannot be queried in SQL anymore (because the database has no idea what those bytes mean).

Answer (score -1):

Java provides classes to support writing object state to streams and restoring objects from streams. `java.io.Serializable` is an **Marker Interface** which provides ability to selialize the object's state of your class(which implements Serializable) in DB table,Files or to transfer over network etc.

Comment: No, it's not. JDBC setString/setInt is used to store the object state.

Comment: I understand that it is possible to save the state of an object through seriazisable interface (through the transformation of this a set of bits), but in the link you put above, the attributes of the class to persist are stored in the database like any other data (could have done the same thing without the serializable interface)

am I right?