# Hibernate mapping exception while saving a collection

Tags: java, hibernate

```
Hi I am new to Hibernate and I am getting the following exception while trying to save a collection.

Could not determine type for: java.util.List, for columns

**Here are my codes**

    @Entity
    @Table(name="USER_DETAILS")

    public class User {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int id;
        @ElementCollection
        private List<Address> aList=new ArrayList<Address>();


        @Embeddable

        public class Address {

        @Column(length=50)
        private String city;

        @Column(length=50)
        private String state;

        @Column(length=50)
        private String country;

        @Column(length=10)
        private int zip;
}

@Embeddable
public class Address implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(length=50)
    private String city;

    @Column(length=50)
    private String state;

    @Column(length=50)
    private String country;

    @Column(length=10)
    private int zip;

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

        public class TestUser {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            User user=new User();
            Address addr=new Address();

            addr.setCity("Asjasjs");
            addr.setCountry("gfgf");
            addr.setState("atyty");
            addr.setZip(345343);

            user.getaList().add(addr);

            Session session=SessionFactoryUtil.getSession();
            session.beginTransaction();

            session.save(user);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();

        }
```

This is how it stores the data in database
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need a table in database where `Address` will be stored. That table needs to have all the columns that are mapped in `Address` class, plus one column which is used to relate it to table `USER_DETAILS`

With this in place, the mapping for `aList` field will look like this

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "ADDRESS", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_DETAILS_ID")})
private List<Address> aList=new ArrayList<Address>();
```

Comment: I did this but it says that Student is not Serializable then I implement Serializable interface then it stored the serialized object in the database. Why this is happning?

Comment: It is generaly good practice for all entities to implement Serializable, but [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2021640/4074715) for more info.

Comment: I know the concept behind it but it stored the serialize object by making a column by the collection name eg: column name is  aList and it stored the serialize object into it and in the USER_DETAILS table it did not create any new table.

Comment: You didn't mention `Student` in your question, there is no code so I can't tell for sure, but JPA probably tries to serialize the collection (of Students) if mapped to single column. That's why you got that Serializable exception. However, in the database it will not be in a readable form, and I don't think you could query on it. I'm not even sure  that deserialization will work without custom code, that should be tested.

Comment: That is no Student class it is Address class. I have added all the code.

Comment: If you don't put `@CollectionTable` on `aList`, the whole list will be serialized into a single column (`USER_DETAILS#ALIST`), like in your screenshot. For this, `Address` needs to be serializable, hence the message you got. With `@CollectionTable` you will need a table for address data, as I explained in my answer. Is there anything else that is not working?

Comment: Even if I used the annotation @CollectionTable(name = "ADDRESS", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_DETAILS_ID")}) it says Student is not serializable, So I implement Serializable.

Comment: OK, and does everything work then? Serializable is not required for entities but it is good practice, as I said, so maybe JPA requires serializable objects whenever `@ElementCollection` is used, regardless of `@CollectionTable`. I don't know this for sure, just my guess.