# Hibernate Reverse Engineering not generating proper domain code STS

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, reverse-engineering

I have started a project in Spring and was successfully able to run a sample application on Spring communicating with one table in MySQL database.

Now, for learning purpose, I created two more tables in that same database and want to generate domain classes by Reverse Engineering from Hibernate Tools.
I followed https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/ this tutorial. My classes are getting generated but it doesn't contain any annotations or mappings which an entity/domain class should contain. Below is the code generated for reference:

```
// default package
// Generated Mar 29, 2018 8:18:21 AM by Hibernate Tools 5.2.8.Final

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Product generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Product implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer productId;
    private String productName;
    private String createdBy;
    private Date createdDate;
    private String modifiedBy;
    private Date modifiedDate;
    private Set measurmentCategories = new HashSet(0);

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public Product(String productName, String createdBy, Date createdDate, String modifiedBy, Date modifiedDate,
            Set measurmentCategories) {
        this.productName = productName;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
        this.measurmentCategories = measurmentCategories;
    }

    public Integer getProductId() {
        return this.productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(Integer productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return this.productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return this.createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return this.createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public String getModifiedBy() {
        return this.modifiedBy;
    }

    public void setModifiedBy(String modifiedBy) {
        this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    }

    public Date getModifiedDate() {
        return this.modifiedDate;
    }

    public void setModifiedDate(Date modifiedDate) {
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }

    public Set getMeasurmentCategories() {
        return this.measurmentCategories;
    }

    public void setMeasurmentCategories(Set measurmentCategories) {
        this.measurmentCategories = measurmentCategories;
    }

}
```

Though, the class should contain an annotation @Entity, and all variables should contain a proper annotations. But it's not there in the generated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In “Exporter” tab make sure `Generate EJB3 annotations` is checked.

Comment: Sukhpal, by default it is implementing java.io.Serializable interface. Should Spring models/domains implement this interface? Because the Spring tutorial I followed, they didn't implement this interface while creating a domain class manually.

Comment: Not required by the specification though. For more information read similar answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020904/when-and-why-jpa-entities-should-implement-serializable-interface

Comment: I have checked both checkboxes but still, annotations are not generated. I checked each as well (one by one) with no positive results. Each time it generates java classes without annotations.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that you selected the Hibernate version as 5.2.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `Generate EJB3 annotations`, make sure to select `Annotations (jdk 1.5+)` in the hibernate configuration "Main" tab.

Comment: I have checked both checkboxes but still, annotations are not generated. I checked each as well (one by one) with no positive results. Each time it generates java classes without annotations