# Having an issue with One To Many and Many To One spring jpa app. getting a class cannot be serialized error

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am having an issue with a bidirectional mapping. and when I try to post or get I get a error class site cant be serialized. if I take away the mappedby in the site then it works just fine and take always the site field in the inventory it will work is that the right way?

```
11:24:52.341 [main] INFO  - in 3.977 seconds (JVM running for 4.471)
11:25:36.453 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  com.cbcse.controller.SiteController - I Fell in here
11:25:36.533 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] WARN  com.cbcse.service.SiteServiceImpl - Handling of [org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException] resulted in Exception
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:571)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)     
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)   
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)    
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy107.save(Unknown Source)
        at com.cbcse.service.SiteServiceImpl.add(SiteServiceImpl.java:71)
        at com.cbcse.controller.SiteController.add(SiteController.java:53)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)  
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562)
        ... 66 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.cbcse.entity.Site cannot be cast to class java.io.Serializable (com.cbcse.entity.Site is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.io.Serializable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.getKeyOfOwner(CollectionType.java:446)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections.processReachableCollection(Collections.java:166)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.FlushVisitor.processCollection(FlushVisitor.java:53)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:104)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:65)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:59)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:183)
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:229)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:93)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1416)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:507)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3299)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2434)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
        ... 67 common frames omitted
```

```java
@Entity
public class Site {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    String name;

    String date;

    String suite;

    String unit;

    long siteId;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy="sites", fetch = FetchType.LAZY ,cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH},orphanRemoval = true)
    List<Inventory> inventory = new ArrayList<>();

   // @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY ,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
   // List<SiteFiles> siteFiles = new ArrayList<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSiteName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setSiteName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSiteDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setSiteDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getSiteSuite() {
        return suite;
    }

    public void setSiteSuite(String suite) {
        this.suite = suite;
    }

    public String getSiteUnit() {
        return unit;
    }

    public void setSiteUnit(String unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }

    public Long getSiteId() {
        return siteId;
    }

    public void setSiteId(Long siteId) {
        this.siteId = siteId;
    }

    public List<Inventory> getInventory() {
        return inventory;
    }

    public void setInventory(List<Inventory> inventory) {
        this.inventory = inventory;
    }  
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Inventory {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    
    Long parentId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY ,cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId", referencedColumnName = "siteId",insertable= false, updatable= false)
    private Site sites;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public Site getSites() {
        return sites;
    }

    public void setSites(Site sites) {
        this.sites = sites;
    }
}
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.cbcse.entity.Site cannot be cast to class java.io.Serializable (com.cbcse.entity.Site is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @7c105899; java.io.Serializable is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When and why JPA entities should implement the Serializable interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020904/when-and-why-jpa-entities-should-implement-the-serializable-interface)

Comment: Already edited and suggestion comment is there